# How to distribute app for testing without dev account?

Tags: ios, testing, testflight

I have recently developed an iOS app. I don't have an Apple dev account(the one which needs $99). I have been testing my app on my iPhone. Now one sponsor wants to test the app. He lives in a far away place. How can I install the app on his device?

I have heard about TestFlight and Diwai.
Please give me insight if I can distribute my app for testing to a device beyond my reach. And How?

I know this question is off topic but please help me. Once I understand the process, I will also delete the question if commenters ask for it.

-- A newbie in need of help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe something like this is currently possible. In order to distribute an app, you need to generate an archive (`.ipa` file) for it, and doing so requires a paid developer account. The closest you can currently get is send your sponsor your source code and instruct them on how to get a free developer account and use Xcode to run it on their own device